# COM object only works in VB.NET not C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, com, interop

I have a COM object that works fine in VB.NET, but not in C#. Both projects are .NET 4 console applications.

The COM object loads in C#, but the methods don't return any values. Why would it work in VB.NET and not C#?

Thanks!

```
Sub Main()
    Dim server As New NoahVersionLib.Version

    Dim val As Int32

    server.GetNoahServerVersionMS(val)



End Sub


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var server = new NoahVersionLib.Version();

        int val= 0;

        server.GetNoahServerVersionMS(ref val);
    }
```

val is 0 in the C# build, but has a value in the VB.NET build.

UPDATE:
I needed to put [STAThread] on my Main() in C#.  It works now.

Comment: Code? Or are we guessing..?

Comment: please show a minimal but working (i.e. compiling) code sample illustrating the problem in both environmnents. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: There's no special reason why it would only work in VB.NET and not in C#. They compile down to the same code. The only way that we can answer this question is if you provide us with a minimal sample that reproduces the behavior. Chances are, there's an error in how you're converting the VB.NET code into C#.

Comment: Have a look at both exe files in `ildasm`. Do you see a difference in the generated IL code? If yes, what is it?

Comment: also, it makes on difference in the C# build if var is used instead of NoadVersionLib.Version.

Comment: what happens if you change the C# int val = 0, to int val = -1 ?

Comment: the call returns -1 in C# build

Answer (score 1):

I needed to put [STAThread] on my Main() in C#. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following in C#?

```
static void Main(string[] args)    
{        
    NoahVersionLib.Version server = new NoahVersionLib.Version();        
    Int32 val= 0;        
    server.GetNoahServerVersionMS(ref val);    
}
```

The only differences between your 2 versions are that you are using `var` instead of declaring the actual type, allowing the compiler to potentially infer an incorrect type (unlikely, but surely possible); and use of `int` instead of `Int32`. As far as I know, int == Int32, but possibly in some weird corner case of COM, it may not..?